# How do Text Objects in PDF work?

Tags: pdf, watermark, text-extraction

I have a PDF document of which I would like to remove watermarks as automatically as possible to get better results from `pdftotext`.

After uncompressing it with `pdftk` I see the watermark almost in plain text:

```
BT
1 0 0 1 277.40012 755.2005 Tm
0.501961 0.501961 0.501961 rg /R1 gs /R2 8 Tf
[()]TJ
0 0 Td
[(Abc)30(defghi K)30(lm)-40(no)]TJ
-5.423981 -9.600038 Td
[()]TJ
0 0 Td
[(Apr 01, 2017 12:34)]TJ
ET
```

The watermark is

```
Abcdefghi Klmno
Apr 01, 2017 12:34
```

After skimming through [Document management — Portable document format](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (especially page 248f), I found the following:

```
BT: Begin Text
Tm: Text matrix - what is that?
x y Td: Move to the start of the next line with an offset of (x, y)
TJ: Text showing
Tf: Text state
ET: End Text
```

What I don't understand is all the numbers and why

```
[(Abc)30(defghi K)30(lm)-40(no)]TJ
```

Does it increase the space between `Abc` and `defghi K` and decrease the space between `lm` and `no` (seems so, looking at Figure 46 on page 259)? By what unit?

What does `Tf` do?

Could somebody please explain that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I don't understand is all the numbers and why
>
> ```
> [(Abc)30(defghi K)30(lm)-40(no)]TJ
> ```
>
> Does it increase the space between `Abc` and `defghi K` and decrease the space between `lm` and `no` (seems so, looking at Figure 46 on page 259)?

Nearly so, the positive value *decreases* and the negative value *increases*, cf. *Table 109 – Text-showing operators* in the PDF specification:

> *array*
>   **TJ** :
>   Show one or more text strings, allowing individual glyph positioning. Each element of *array* shall be either a string or a number. If the element is a string, this operator shall show the string. If it is a number, the operator shall adjust the text position by that amount; that is, it shall translate the text matrix, *T*<sub>m</sub>. The number shall be expressed in thousandths of a unit of text space (see 9.4.4, "Text Space Details"). This amount shall be *subtracted* from the current horizontal or vertical coordinate, depending on the writing mode. In the default coordinate system, a positive adjustment has the effect of moving the next glyph painted either to the left or down by the given amount. Figure 46 shows an example of the effect of passing offsets to **TJ**.

The figure is misleading, obviously some type-setting program scrambled up the effect the author wanted to show. The actual source of the figure looks like this:

```
BT
/T1_2 1 Tf
0 Tc 8.7503 0 0 8.7503 118.989 450.2115 Tm
[([ \()11(A)53(W)57(A)79(Y again\) ] )41(T)43(J)]TJ
40.0016 0 0 40.0015 296.9949 440.2111 Tm
[(A)53(W)57(A)79(Y again)]TJ
8.7503 0 0 8.7503 118.989 403.2097 Tm
[([ \()11(A)9(\) 120 \()-50(W)-55(\) 120 \()11(A)9(\) 95 \()-41(Y again\) ] )41(T)43(J)]TJ
40.0016 0 0 40.0015 296.9949 392.2093 Tm
(AWAY again)Tj
ET
```

---

> By what unit?

*thousandths of a unit of text space,* cf. the quote above.

> *Text space* is the coordinate system in which text is shown. It shall be defined by the text matrix, *T*<sub>m</sub>, and the text state parameters *T*<sub>fs</sub>, *T*<sub>h</sub>, and *T*<sub>rise</sub>, which together shall determine the transformation from text space to user space.

This often coincides with a single unit in glyph space

---

> What does `Tf` do?

According to *Table 105 – Text state operators* in the PDF specification

> *font size* **Tf** :
>   Set the text font, *T*<sub>f</sub>, to *font* and the text font size, *T*<sub>fs</sub>, to *size*. *font* shall be the name of a font resource in the **Font** subdictionary of the current resource dictionary; *size* shall be a number representing a scale factor. There is no initial value for either *font* or *size*; they shall be specified explicitly by using **Tf** before any text is shown.

---

> The only thing I don't understand now is the line
>
> ```
> 0.501961 0.501961 0.501961 rg /R1 gs /R2 8 Tf
> ```
>
> Can you explain that, too?

The instruction

```
0.501961 0.501961 0.501961 rg
```

sets the fill color to a medium gray in an RGB color space.

Then

```
/R1 gs
```

sets additional graphics state parameters from the **ExtGState** resource named **R1**; probably here some transparency effect is defined.

Finally

```
/R2 8 Tf
```

sets the font to one defined by the **Font** resource named **R2** and the font size to 8.

Comment: Thank you (+1)! The only thing I don't understand now is the line `0.501961 0.501961 0.501961 rg /R1 gs /R2 8 Tf`. Can you explain that, too?

Comment: Ok, I figured out most of it. Only the `\R1 gs \R2` is still unclear to me. Are `\R1` and `\R2` variables? What should I look for to find them in the document?

Comment: **R1** and **R2** are resource names. You have to look into the current resource dictionary (if you found the instructions in a page content stream, look for the page resource dictionary - which can be inherited from ancestors in the page tree).

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer

### Tf

```
font size Tf
```

sets the font and the size (see page 244)

### gs

`dictName gs` sets the graphic state:

> (PDF 1.2) Set the specified parameters in the graphics state.
>   dictName shall be the name of a graphics state parameter
>   dictionary in the ExtGState subdictionary of the current resource
>   dictionary (see the next sub-clause).

I am not too sure what `\R1` means.

### rg

```
1.0 1.0 0.0 rg % Set nonstroking colour to yellow
```

Hence `0.501961 0.501961 0.501961 rg` sets the color to some gray value.

### Text matrix

The Text matrix is an affine transformation matrix as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17202701/562769).

Hence

```
1 0 0 1 0 0 Tf
```

doesn't change anything.

The matrix `1 0 0 1 277.40012 755.2005 Tm` moves the text right (?) by `277.40012` text units (?) and down by `755.2005` text units.