# TJ and Td offset difference

Tags: pdf

I have some text that I want to edit (justified text, really annoying), so I was wondering if this:

```
BT /FAAABA 10 Tf 
1 0 0 -1 0 9.38000011 Tm 
(Some) Tj
36.77199936 0 Td 
(text) Tj 
38.4280014 0 Td 
(stuff) Tj
33.42799759 0 Td

...
```

is equivalent to this:

```
BT
/FAAABA 10 Tf
1 0 0 -1 0 9.38000011 Tm
[(Some)-36.77199936*1000(text)-38.4280014*1000(stuff)-33.42799759*1000] TJ
...
```

Comment: The **TJ** array parameter may contain strings and numbers but not expressions like `-36.77199936*1000`.

Comment: Yes, I just meant the conversion since TJ numbers are expressed in thousandths of units of text space and Td are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming horizontal text we determined in my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52095195/1729265) that the horizontal displacement *t<sub>x</sub>* corresponding to a number *T<sub>j</sub>* in a **TJ** array can be calculated as

> t<sub>x</sub> = (−T<sub>j</sub> / 1000) × T<sub>fs</sub> × T<sub>h</sub>

where *T<sub>fs</sub>* is the current font size and *T<sub>h</sub>* is the current horizontal scaling factor.

Thus, if you have a horizontal displacement *t<sub>x</sub>* and want to calculate the corresponding number *T<sub>j</sub>* for a **TJ** array, you simply resolve the equation above to:

> T<sub>j</sub> = -1000 × t<sub>x</sub> / (T<sub>fs</sub> × T<sub>h</sub>)

**BUT** this is not exactly the situation in your case because **Td** does *not* simply shift the *text matrix* by its parameters but instead shifts the *text line matrix* by them and sets the text matrix to the new text line matrix value:

> *t<sub>x</sub> t<sub>y</sub>*
>   **Td**
>   Move to the start of the next line, offset from the start of the current line by (*t<sub>x</sub>, t<sub>y</sub>*). *t<sub>x</sub>* and *t<sub>y</sub>* shall denote numbers expressed in unscaled text space units. More precisely, this operator shall perform these assignments:
>
> [image]

*(ISO 32000-1, Table 108 – Text-positioning operators)*

Thus, the *t<sub>x</sub>* parameter of **Td** is not the *t<sub>x</sub>* to put into the equation above but you instead have to subtract the width of the text drawn since the last setting of the text line matrix.

So to transform your example

```
BT /FAAABA 10 Tf 
1 0 0 -1 0 9.38000011 Tm 
(Some) Tj
36.77199936 0 Td 
(text) Tj 
38.4280014 0 Td 
(stuff) Tj
33.42799759 0 Td
```

into a

```
BT
/FAAABA 10 Tf
1 0 0 -1 0 9.38000011 Tm
[(Some) NUM1 (text) NUM2 (stuff) NUM3] TJ
```

form, you calculate the numeric values `NUM1`, `NUM2`, and `NUM3` like this:

> NUM1 = -1000 × (36.77199936 - width("Some")) / (T<sub>fs</sub> × T<sub>h</sub>)
>
> NUM2 = -1000 × (38.4280014 - width("text")) / (T<sub>fs</sub> × T<sub>h</sub>)
>
> NUM3 = -1000 × (33.42799759 - width("stuff")) / (T<sub>fs</sub> × T<sub>h</sub>)

When calculating the widths of those strings remember to take the font size, the character spacing, and the horizontal scaling into account!

And even then the two forms are not identical because the text line matrix at the end differs.

Comment: Thank you! This was very informative! Now to get the string width, I'll have to get the glyphs' widths, is it possible to use the FontBBox [x1 y1 x2 y2] and do x2-x1?

Comment: @maybefreedom *"I'll have to get the glyphs' widths, is it possible to use the FontBBox [x1 y1 x2 y2] and do x2-x1?"* - The font boundary box can only be used if all characters of a font have the same width. Otherwise you need the individual widths for each character code.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help!